$\frac{d}{ds} |x(s)-p|\bigg|_{s=0}=0$
Suppose you have a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then look at the semicircle $S$ with ends 0 and $p$. Furthermore, let $q\in S$, then the triangle with corners $0,p,q$ has a right angle at $q$ by Thales theorem. Now you take $q(s)\in S$, where $|q(s)|=|q|+s$ and let $x(s)$ be the intersection point of the line through $q(s),p$ and the line through $q,0$. That means, the triangle with corners $q,p,x(s)$ has a right angle at $q$ and $q(s)\in\overline{x(s)p}$. Now we evaluate the distance $s\mapsto|x(s)-p|$, $s\geq0$. In the paper I am studying it says $\frac{d}{ds}|x(s)-p|\bigg|_{s=0}=0$ but I have no idea why and the hint says to use orthogonality but that does not lead me anywhere.

Have you considered differentiating $$|x(s)-p|^2 = |q-p|^2 + |x(s)-q|^2$$  with respect to $s$?

yes. However, I am no closer to the solutions by my attempts. Because I do not know anything about the behaviour of $\frac{d}{ds}|x(s)-q|$

What is $\lim\limits_{s\to 0^+} x'(s)\cdot (x(s)-q)$?

Well, depends on the behaviour of $x'$ which I have a hard time deducing. Furthermore we have to take into account, how fast $x(s)$ goes to $q$ as
$s\downarrow 0$.

No, as long as $|x'(s)|$ is bounded, the dot product approaches $0$ because $x(s)\to q$ as $s\to 0^+$. One way to deal with $|x'(s)|$ is to write $x(s)=\lambda(s)q$ and solve for $\lambda(s)$. You get $\lambda'(0)=q\cdot q'(0)$.

@TedShifrin After some attempts of calculating myself, I seem do not see your result, which leaves me with two follow-up questions: Firstly, I was not able to solve for $\lambda$ while my guess is by your form, that $\lambda(s)=q\cdot q(s)$. Secondly, in order to bound $|x'(s)|$ it would be necessary that $q'(s)$ is bounded. How to derive that? PS: I am sorry for taking your time, I am somewhat irrititated right now about the progress.

Where did you find all this, anyhow? The author's use of $s$ is admittedly a bit annoying for those of us who work with the Frenet equations of a curve in our sleep. $s$ is of course not the arclength of the semicircle (measured from $q$), but the arclength $\sigma$ satisfies $\sigma> |q(s)-q| = s$, and this will bound $q'(0)$ above by the length of the unit tangent (which, of course, is $1$).

So the article is https://ghomi.math.gatech.edu/Papers/sphere.pdf by Mr Ghomi and Mr Wenk. While I understand now how to bound $x'$, I still cannot follow you, how you calculate $\lambda(s)$ explicitly?

Ah, I know Ghomi. I suspect he may have had something easier in mind, but perhaps not. Anyhow, I've added an answer with more details, although it may not be optimal.

Here is a sketch of the argument I suggested in the comments. Some of what I suggested was extraneous.
You asked for the derivative of $|x(s)-p|$ at $s=0^+$. We have
$$|x(s)-p|^2 = |x(s)-q|^2 + |q-p|^2,$$
and so $(x(s)-p)\cdot x'(s) = (x(s)-q)\cdot x'(s)$.
$$\frac d{ds}\Big|_{s=0^+}|x(s)-p| = \lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{(x(s)-p)\cdot x'(s)}{|x(s)-p|} = \lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{(x(s)-q)\cdot x'(s)}{|x(s)-p|}.$$
Well, $|(x(s)-q)\cdot x'(s)|\le |x(s)-q||x'(s)| \to 0$, since $x(s)\to q$ and $|x'|$ is bounded as $s\to 0^+$ I will now sketch a justification of that claim.
As I complained in a comment, $s$ is not arclength (measured from $q$) along the semicircle, but it is related. Indeed, if $\sigma(s)$ is the arclength from $q$ to $q(s)$, we have $\sigma>|q(s)-q|=s$, so $$|q'(0)| = \left|\lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{q(s)-q}s\right| \le \left|\lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{q(s)-q}{\sigma(s)}\right| = 1.$$
But we have $x(s)=\lambda(s)q=p+\mu(s)(q(s)-p)$ for appropriate functions $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Therefore, dotting with $q$, we obtain
$$\lambda(s) = \frac1{|q|^2}\left((p+\mu(s)(q(s)-p))\cdot q\right),$$
and, using $(q-p)\cdot q=0$, we have $$|x'(0)|=\lambda'(0)|q| \le \frac1{|q|}|(\mu'(0)(q-p)+\mu(0)q'(0))\cdot q|\le |q'(0)\cdot q|\le 1.$$
